# OCSP blocking SSL of the local server

Tags: ssl, tomcat, certificate, tomcat7, ocsp

I need help figuring out why my config is not working with OCSP required browsers (eg. Firefox).

My server is, a local area network accessible, Windows Tomcat7 server. It is set with wildcard certificate (eg. for *.mydomain.com). I have created pkcs12 certificate for Tomcat using private key, signed certificate and bundle of root CA.

My server address is 192.168.X.X and I am using domain like system.mydomain.com - it works fine with any browser except Firefox with OCSP enabled. For most browser or if I disable OCSP in Firefox it works - certificate is valid, page is loading. Otherwise I have "SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE" error.

My Tomcat7 connector looks like this:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:/Tomcat7/keystore/file.p12" keystorePass="password" keystoreType="PKCS12"/>
```

My question is what am I missing? Is it not possible to use OCSP with local servers? Does it requires public access to validate or something? Or am I missing something on my Tomcat connector configuration or else?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was wrong with the configuration.
Unizeto provided us with more then one certificate. It looked like there was not difference, both were valid, but I have rebuild keystore using other one and it works like a charm.

So bottom line is it was just wrong certificate (althoug valid it was not working with OSCP)